# Concatenate every incoming response to Object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I want to concatenate every response from `resnews` to ojbect properties called `newsObj.getNews`.

The API calls when the page first loads and keep loading when we scroll down. I want to add every incoming response (which has a limit of 10) to an object property.

Right now every time the API is called it is overlapping the data in `newsObj.getNews` and shows only 10.

```
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    data: newsParams,
    success: function(resnews) {
        // app.preloader.hide();
        if(resnews.status == 'ok') {
            if(type=="relevancy"){                      
                newsObj.getNews = resnews.articles; // overlapping my response 
                console.log(typeof resnews.articles); //returns object
                _self.renderNewsInUIAppend(resnews.articles, type)
            } else {
                newsObj.popular = resnews.articles;
                console.log(typeof newsObj);//returns object
                _self.renderNewsInUIAppend(resnews.articles, type);
            }
        } else {
            console.warn("There was error fetching error.");
        }
    }
})
```

My response from `newsObj.getNews`

[image]

Comment: `newsObj.getNews` is an array?

Comment: No it is an object.

Comment: Can you post the `newsObj.getNews` data here in the question?

Comment: I added the json data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeof []` will give "object" because array is an object

```js
console.log(typeof [])
```

You can find the explanation from [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/arrayobject.htm)

And you are looping array of objects to display the data. So you can concate the new data with the old data like below

```js
var latestNews;
var newsObj = {};
var resNews = {};
resNews.articles = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}];

// At first newsObj.getNews is undefined like below
console.log(newsObj.getNews);

// So you need to do like below
if (typeof newsObj.getNews !== "undefined") {
  latestNews = newsObj.getNews.concat(resNews.articles);
  newsObj.getNews = latestNews;
} else {
  newsObj.getNews = resNews.articles;
}

console.log(newsObj.getNews);

// New news
resNews.articles = [{id: 3}, {id: 4}];

setTimeout(function () {
  latestNews = newsObj.getNews.concat(resNews.articles);
  newsObj.getNews = latestNews;
  console.log(newsObj.getNews);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But I had tried this way. I dont have `arr1` and `arr2`. I did using `result = resnews.articles; result =result.concat(resnews.articles);` It seems concatenate same response which is called for the first time.

Comment: @Santosh No that is only example explanation. You can simply do like `newsObj.getNews.concat(resnews.articles)`

Comment: Okay I understood the problem, at first `newObj.getNews` will be undefined

Comment: Do like this `if (typeof newObj.getNews !== undefined) { newObj.getNews.concat(resnews.articles) } else { newObj.getNews = resnews.articles }`

Comment: @Santosh did you get the output?

Comment: No @skt It still shows same error as shown in screenshot I shared

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179709/discussion-between-santosh-and-javascript-lover-skt).